# Bad Links resolve

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, google-ads-api

I am using wordpress to create a website. I have shifted my website to new domain but i have used the backup of old domain name.

now the old domain is not owned by me someone else has booked it. i am trying to apply for google ads but every time i try to apply they reject my request due to bad links.

my previous domain was `.com` now i have `.com.au` domain, report shows bad links associated with old domain.

can anyone guide me how to remove these links

Comment: Do you have ssh access to you server, bec I'm thinking that you still have som old links is your database. So you need todo an search-replace in the databse from your old domain to your new domain. And the most easiest way I know is thru wp-cli

Comment: no i don't have the access to ssh

Comment: Do you have database access?

Comment: Yes I have access to database